# You must SSH in as root to run this command: sudo

Tags: 16.04, ssh, sudo, vagrant

I keep seeing this whenever enter `sudo` on different user than `ubuntu`

> You must SSH in as root to run this command: sudo

Here is the output of `sudo -l -U myuser`

```
Matching Defaults entries for serverpilot on ubuntu-xenial:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User myuser may run the following commands on ubuntu-xenial:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I added `myuser` to `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-user`
I'm using `Vagrant` to manage my machines.

P/s: Before I posted this, I'm still able to add new sudo user by above way without any problems. (Previous ubuntu boxes version)

Comment: Are you running a restricted shell or something?

Comment: @muru No I didn't. The only way to get move on is set `env bash` inside .bash_profile. Is that make any sense to you? Because I never seen this before...

Answer (score 0):

Serverpilot is doing this deliberately for unknown reasons.
It doesn't actually prevent use of sudo which you can verify with
which sudo

```
/usr/bin/sudo
```

and if you call sudo with full path it works fine.
e.g.

```
/usr/bin/sudo whoami
```

an alias is being set in

```
/etc/profile.d/serverpilot-aliases.sh

if [[ "$HOME" == /srv/users/* ]]; then
   alias sudo='echo "You must SSH in as "root" to run this command: sudo"'
fi
```

you can confirm with
`alias`

```
alias sudo='echo "You must SSH in as "root" to run this command: sudo"'
```

You can fix it temporarily with

```
unalias sudo
```

Serverpilot would need to show up and account for their weird decision.
You can fix permanently by removing that alias declaration from the file listed.
Doing so may have unknown and unintended effects on serverpilot. Surely they did it for a reason...